# Does code within NextJS API feature exposed to client side

Tags: mysql, next.js

It is well known that [nextjs API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) provide a straightforward solution to build your API with Next.js. and that any file inside the folder pages/api is mapped to /api/* and will be treated as an API endpoint instead of a page.

I have just one doubt: is the code within the pages/api exposed to the world? I mean, can I build some logic there that has some key that must be hidden or maybe some MySQL connection?

Comment: Do you mean "What parts of my Next.js application are visible to end-users?"

Comment: Yes. What parts? I see that the folder `pages/api` is there like a middleware. Does the code there is visible to client-side?

Comment: It really depends what's server-side vs. client-side. If it's client-side you'll be able to see it. Server-side elements should not be visible, but could accidentally be included if you `import` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not `/api` is in any way exposed to the world I do not know for sure, but according to [Next documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction), "they are server-side only bundles."

In general though, for any key/sql connection that you want to run, I would put that into an `.env.local` file on your machine, a file that gets git ignored and never uploaded, and if you are hosting on Vercel, then use their environmental variables to store sensitive information.

You'd find environmental variables under:
{Your Account}/{Project}/Settings/Environmental Variables

p.s. Also from Next.js docs, I think you'd find this bit on [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#write-server-side-code-directly) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Nextjs Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations#:%7E:text=Good%20to%20know%3A&text=Since%20API%20Routes%20run%20on,the%20security%20of%20your%20application.), "since API Routes run on the server, we're able to use sensitive values (like API keys) through Environment Variables without exposing them to the client. This is critical for the security of your application."

So you should be safe when using sensitive variables in the api routes that run on the server when you're running code in the pages/api files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using `/pages/api/*` as a backend server (i.e. you are making HTTP requests). If that's the case then, no, the keys are not revealed to the client. I think you actually have to prefix with NEXT_PUBLIC_ to reveal them to the client (probably so you don't shoot yourself in the foot by revealing environment variables). Also, it's a good idea to use the next.config file for keeping environment variables organized.

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, if you don't want to expose an API externally, you can use authentication information to validate requests. However, this method alone may not be sufficient to completely prevent the exposure of the API. Therefore, for APIs where exposure is a concern, it's more advisable not to set them up as separate APIs but to handle the logic using Server-Side Rendering (SSR) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't exposed to the world itself. It runs on the server. It's secure to use sensitive keys but be aware do not pass it to the external world.

Be aware to not commit an development error of exposing it to the external world by returning it in the response.

Every code that runs only on server is not exposed in the same way that client-side code. You can think of NextJS Api actions as proxy to run sensitive operation that code or credentials can't be exposed to the world. You only get the code if you access the server.